# Create multidimensional array in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Currently I am trying create an array multidimensional in php using two queries (Items and Categories).
I made a search in the site but I did not found anything similar to what I am looking for.
I appreciate if someone can help me using my code.

Please se bellow what am looking for and my code.

Tables:

```
TABLE Items;

+-----------------------------------+
|    id    |    type    |    name   |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     1    |     4      |  item_1   |       
|     2    |     3      |  item_2   |
|     3    |     2      |  item_3   |
+-----------------------------------+

TABLE Categories;

+-----------------------------------+
|    id    |   Item_id  |    name   |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     1    |     2      |   Cat_a   |       
|     2    |     2      |   Cat_b   |
|     3    |     3      |   Cat_x   |
|     4    |     3      |   Cat_z   |
|     5    |     3      |   Cat_b   |
|     6    |     1      |   Cat_b   |
|     7    |     3      |   Cat_y   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Result that I am looking for:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            id   => 1
            name => Item_1
            Type => 4
            cats => Array
                (
                    [6] => Cat_b
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            id   => 2
            name => Item_2
            Type => 3
            cats => Array
                (
                    [1] => Cat_a
                    [2] => Cat_b
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            id   => 3
            name => Item_3
            Type => 2
            cats => Array
                (
                    [3] => Cat_x
                    [4] => Cat_z
                    [5] => Cat_b
                    [7] => Cat_y
                )
        )
)
```

My code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE Item_id = '233'");


foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $v[] = $value["id"];
}

    foreach ($v as $key => $res) {
        $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE category_id = '".$res."'");
           foreach ($query as $k =>$att){
                 $var[$res][] =  $att["name"]; 
          }
    }

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($var,1) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: I think I know what he is trying to attempt

Comment: he is trying to list out all categories per item, but over complicated it in his code

Comment: For each item > list out corresponding item category, and then add them to an array

Comment: Yes, im trying list all categories per Item... if someone can share something I appreciate :)

Comment: I know it should be easy, but I find this kind of thing really difficult too, Anyway, it looks like you're nearly there. But you should only have one query. Not 1 + n queries; that's a really bad idea.

Comment: I don't see `category_id`  column in Items table and you have used with your query. Is that query `SELECT * FROM Items WHERE category_id = 1` gives any result without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following, Tested and working

```
$sql = "SELECT i.id,i.name,i.type,c.id AS CatKey,c.name As catName FROM `Items` AS i JOIN Categories AS c ON i.id=c.Item_id ORDER BY i.id ASC ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$res = array();
$i = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $ids = array_column($res, 'id');
       if(in_array($row['id'], $ids)){
            $res[$i-1]['cats'][$row['CatKey']] = $row['catName'];
       }else{
        $res[$i]['id']   = $row['id'];
        $res[$i]['type'] = $row['type'];
        $res[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $res[$i]['cats'] = array($row['CatKey'] => $row['catName']);
        $i++;
       }
    }
} 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

Result:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => 4
            [name] => item_1
            [cats] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Cat_b
                )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [type] => 3
        [name] => item_2
        [cats] => Array
            (
                [1] => Cat_a
                [2] => Cat_b
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [type] => 2
        [name] => item_3
        [cats] => Array
            (
                [3] => Cat_x
                [4] => Cat_z
                [5] => Cat_b
                [7] => Cat_y
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can gather the data needed in one SQL statement. Then you basically do a break-sort to group the category with the items.

```
$qstr = "SELECT
    a.`id` as `item_id`,
    a.`type` as `item_type`,
    a.`name` as `item_name`,
    b.`id` as `cat_id`,
    b.`name` as `cat_name`
FROM `Items` a
JOIN `Categories` b
ON a.`id` = b.`item_id`
WHERE Item_id = '233'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $qstr);
    $lastItem = '';
    $rslt = array();
    $rowno = -1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($lastItem != $row['table_id']) {
            $rowno++;
            $rslt[$rowno] = array(
                'id' => $row['item_id'],
                'name' => $row['item_name'],
                'Type' => $row['item_type'],
                'cats' => array($row['cat_id'] => $row['cat_name'])
            );
            $lastItem = $row['table_id'];
        } else {
            $rslt[$rowno]['cats'][$row['cat_id']] = $row['cat_nsme'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not serialize the queries. One query is enough.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 
"select i.id, i.type, i.name, c.id as `cat_id`, c.name as `cat_name`
from Items i
  join Categories c on c.Item_id=i.id
where i.id = '233'
order by i.id, c.id
");


$data = [];
$id = null;
$row_id = -1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  if (is_null($id) || $id != $row['id']) {
    $row_id++;
    $id = $row['id'];
    $data[] = [
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'name' => $row['name'],
      'Type' => $row['type'],
      'cats' => []
    ];
  } 
  $data[$row_id]['cats'][$row['cat_id']] = $row['cat_name'];
}
```